# redirect all /api/.. requests to express

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I currently have a nginx server running with a react app as frontend and a express server as backend.

The express server is running at localhost:5000/

```
  server {
    listen 80 ;

    server_name siteurl;
    server_name siteip;


    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf; # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     location ^~ /api/ {
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
             proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
             proxy_redirect off;



    }


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then

            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            root /usr/share/nginx/site/front;
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

I want all /api/* requests to redirect to my express server, currently when I do site/api/ it goes to my express server, however when doing /api/users it won't go to my express server and will go to my react server.

How would I be able to make this work
thx

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `^~` modifier within the `location` directive, you actually tell nginx that the path following is a regular expression. If so, you have to format it as a regular expression:

```
location ^~ /api/.* {
```

Comment: No it doesn't, now /api won't even go to the express server, just to the react client, also /api/users also goes to the react server.